# rabbitmq server does not receive messages from a python client

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I am trying to publish a message to rabbitmq. this works in production environment env with the same code so I suspect this is a **configuration issue.**

```
rbqueue = RabbitMQClientQueue('cn-dip-v3', host = rabbitmq_config['host'], username = rabbitmq_config['user'], password = rabbitmq_config['password'])

channel = rbqueue.connection.channel()
args = {"x-max-priority": 10}
channel.queue_declare(queue='cn-dip-v3', durable=True, arguments=args)

result = channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
callback_queue = result.method.queue

msgBody = json.dumps({"ohad":123})
# may happen that sendResponseToDal is True but there is no sendResponseToDal method on server side
data = {"body":msgBody,"queue_response" : False}
if responseHandler:
    data["queue_response"] = True

corrID = str(uuid.uuid4())

>>> channel.basic_publish(exchange='',routing_key='cn-dip-v3',properties=pika.BasicProperties(priority = 10, reply_to = callback_queue,correlation_id = corrID,),body=json.dumps(data))
>>>
```

The `queue_declare` works . if I delete it and run the same line the queue gets defined. I see it in the management panel, which is oddly, in port 55672 and not 15672.

[image]
[image]

also, after every time I ran the `channel.basic_publish`, I see another callback queue being added to the queues section in the rabbitmq management.

[image]

all that's missing is the message to get there.

Comment: Your comment about ports makes me suspect you have different versions of the message broker operating. The port for RabbitMQ versions prior to 3.0 is 55672. There are substantial differences in 3.0 and later versions.

Comment: oh man... 4 hours of work..... thanks so much!

Comment: I should have posted as an answer! Haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment about ports makes me suspect you have different versions of the message broker operating. The port for RabbitMQ versions prior to 3.0 is 55672. There are substantial differences in 3.0 and later versions.